# vlookup: lookup_value as date range

Tags: excel, date-range, vlookup

Following Situation:

Sheet 1 provides a date range in two cells:

```
Beginning____End

1.2013______2.2013

2.2013______3.2013...
```

Sheet 2 provides specific dates and values

```
3.1.2013_____500$

5.2.2013_____700$...
```

What I want to do now is insert the Values from Sheet 2 next to the right date ranges in Sheet 1. Please note that there is only one date (and thus one value) for each date range.

```
1.2013___ 2.2013___500$

2.2013___ 3.2013___700$
```

Usually in such a situation I would use Vlookup and match the dates, but that doesn't work since I would have to put a value range as lookup_value.

I would be very thankful for your help. This problem seems so easy but I can't seem to figure out a solution! I tried to apply some solutions for similar problems I found here and on other websites but I haven't found a solution yet.

Thanks and best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether there's an alternative, but this is what I came up with:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(C3,Sheet1!$B$3:$C$11,1)>=B3,VLOOKUP(C3,Sheet1!$B$3:$C$11,2),0)
```

First thing to note is that you had a 'floating' or unanchored range, which caused your `LOOKUP()` to work somewhat, but which would ultimately lead to a lot of wrong values.

To the formula, here's a little description:

`VLOOKUP(C4,Sheet1!$B$3:$C$11,1)>=B4` this checks if the `End of Period` is equal to or before the date in `Sheet1` we're looking for. In case of month skipping, this bit is what takes care of it.

`VLOOKUP(C3,Sheet1!$B$3:$C$11,2)` this looks for the corresponding value of the date.

And I updated your file [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23298677/vlookup.xlsx).

Comment: Good solution! In the current version of your file you've used OFFSET and MATCH, but the formula as posted above works (for the benefit of readers without the example sheet, the specific dates and values are in Sheet1!$B$3:$C$11 and the start/end dates are in columns B and C of the sheet where the above formula is used).

Comment: @nekomatic Oh oops, I tried with Offset and Match the first time round and I guess I forgot to save the updated one with only vlookup. Thanks for pointing that out! I just updated the excel.

Comment: Hey Jerry, hey nekomatic! Thanks a lot for the help, I really like Jerrys solution. Thank you nekomatic for pointing out that VLOOKUP looks either for an exact match or the largest value that is less than the search value. I put jerrys solution into words, that might help not so experienced excel users like myself. Please correct me if I'm wrong: If the largest vlaue that is less than [upper end of range] is bigger or equal to [lower end of range] --> lookup [upper end of range] if not --> write 0

Comment: @PeteSahut I'm not sure whether this is how I'll say it, so I'll rephrase it my way: 1. Find the largest date, which is below the one we're looking for. 2. If this largest date is after (greater than) the value of B3 (Start of period), then it means the date is correct, and fetch the amount. If this largest date is before the value of B3, then this largest date belongs to another period, therefore put 0. But that's basically it.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your dates on Sheet2 are in ascending order, you can still use VLOOKUP. If you check the help for VLOOKUP you'll see that if the `range_lookup` parameter is omitted or TRUE, the function will match the first value that is equal to the search value, **or the largest value that is less than the search value**. So in your example, if cell B2 on Sheet1 contains `2.2013` then `VLOOKUP(Sheet1!B2, Sheet2!$A$1:$B2)` will return 500, because `3.1.2013` is the last value in the search column that's less than the search value (Excel treats a month.year date value as equal to 1.month.year).

If there is **always** a value on Sheet2 for every month - i.e. it never skips from 5.2.2013 to 7.4.2013 for example - then VLOOKUP on its own should do what you need. If there are sometimes missing months on Sheet2 you'll need to limit the search range of the VLOOKUP function to prevent (in this example) the end date `4.2013` from returning the `5.2.2013` value. You can do this using the OFFSET and MATCH functions to construct a range for VLOOKUP's `table_array` that starts at the beginning of the date range you're looking for. Use a `match_type` parameter of 1 in the MATCH function to make it behave in the same way as VLOOKUP.

Comment: Hi nekomatic, thanks for your answer. I tired out your suggestion with VLOOKUP and also tried LOOKUP in following file: [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18406645/vlookup.xlsx) As you said there are problems when months are skiped. Unfortunately that is the case with my data. I wasn't able to fully understand your suggestion with offset and match. Do you by chance have a link that will further explain or could you specify? Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: I tried to construct an example but Jerry's solution was simpler, so I recommend you accept that one :D  As he comments, you need to be careful to specify absolute ranges (using the $ symbol) where appropriate.